# Messy Change Log Levels Window

Tags: governorlimits, developer-console

I'm trying to change the log levels in the **Developer Console** to display the transaction *Limits* , but I noticed that the window now displays +30 Settings, so I have no idea which one I should update. I have a feeling this is some kind of bug, because I remember only having one **General** line before.

[image]

What do you think? Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the `TraceFlag` records that can be accessed via the [Tooling API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/api_tooling.pdf).

When I create TraceFlag entries for a Salesforce User Id with a specific ExpirationDate the older records are still persisted. Each of these older records shows up as a Trace Setting for the user.

**Before (Multiple Log Levels displaying for User General Trace Settings):**
[image: Multiple Log Levels displaying for User General Trace Settings]

**During TraceFlag creation:**
Note that I have 171 existing TraceFlag records that are going to be deleted.
[image: Multiple existing TraceFlag records]

**After:** Additional Trace flags have been removed. One of these is the one I created. I think the other is the one for the developer console log monitoring.
[image]

Comment: And how can I execute a request to delete all the unused one to keep a single entry?

Comment: I had to use the Tooling API directly from code, as I don't know of any other way to access the TraceFlag sObject. Are you using Windows? I could potentially do a special build of the FuseIT SFDC Explorer with functionality to clear the TraceFlags.

Comment: Can you post the code you used to delete all TraceFlags?

Comment: @PabloVenturino I don't have it at the moment. You can see it in the dark screenshot under "During TraceFlag creation". Basically use a SOQL call the get all the TraceFlag records with a matching ScopeId and TracedEntityId. Then delete any records that are returned.